# codeigniter, como acceder a la información al hacer una llamada de 2 funciones a un controlador

Tags: php, codeigniter

Buenas tengo mi controlador..

```
function financieras_disponible()
    {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $con = $_POST['con'];
        $rescate = $this->financieras_rescate_tst1($id);
        $data = $this->getBancos();
}
```

Esto contienen mis otros controladores

```
public function financieras()
    {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        $financieras = array();
        if($id)
        {
            $financieras = array("status" => 'success', "mensaje" => "Solicitud Rescatada", "titulo" => 'Listo!');
            $financieras['financieras'] = $this->Credi->financieras($id);
        }
        else
            $financieras = array("status" => 'error', "mensaje" => "Faltan Parametros", "datos" => array(), "titulo" => 'Error!');

        echo json_encode($financieras);
    }


function getBancos()
    {
        $data =$this->Credi->getBancos();

        if ($data) {

                        $this->output
                        ->set_content_type('application/json')
                        ->set_status_header(200)
                        ->set_output(json_encode(array(
                            "Status" => true,
                            "Message" => "GET",
                            "Data" =>  $data
                        )));
                    }else
                    {
                         $this->output
                        ->set_content_type('application/json')
                        ->set_status_header(500)
                        ->set_output(json_encode(array(
                            "Status" => false,
                            "Message" => "GET"

                        )));
                    }
    }
```

En mi primer controlador `financieras_disponible()` lo voy a usar para cargar un dropdown list.

Segundo controlador `public function financieras()` Me muestra las solicitudes de los bancos en donde halla solicitado un crédito una persona.

Tercer controlador `function getBancos()` Solo me despliega todos los bancos disponibles.

Ahora mi duda es en mi primer controlador como puedo sacar la información que me regresa controlador 2 y 3 , lo que quiero hacer es que en mi controlador 1 hacer validaciones, primero me cargue 2 bancos de prioridad y una vez que en mi controlador `function financieras()` encuentre esos 2 bancos de prioridad registrados entonces me muestre los demás y asi para lo que sigue si encuentra una relación de controlador 2 y controlador 3 no me muestre ese banco, no se si me explique bien.

Comment: Creo que no te estas explicando muy bien, ¿has intentado algo?, fórmula un poco mejor la pregunta.

Comment: si amigo, pude solucionarlo, lo que hice fue en vez de llamar  las dos funciones ($this->getbancos();), lo que hice mejor fue de sacar las consultas y hacerlo todo en 1 y nomas con un ciclo recorri los bancos y los bancos ya solicitados y nomas los meti en un array y listo

Comment: @EduardoJavierMaldonado lo que no me acordaba era la sintaxis para llamar una funcion del controlador pero ya supe nomas era con el $this

Answer (score 0):

No puedes llamar a funciones de un controlador desde otro controlador. En realidad sí pero lo lógico es que tengas esas funciones en un modelo y las llames desde el controlador.
Para llamar a funciones de un controlador a otro, emplea CURL.

```
public function funcion_del_controller1(){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://tupagina.com/controlador2/funcion_del_controlador2',
    ));
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $resp;
}
```

Que la fuerza te acompañe